# Ember.js - Change what a computed property listens to at runtime

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a way to add and remove the properties that a computed property listens to at runtime?

e.g.

```
fullName: function(key, value) {
    //some code here
}.property('firstName', 'lastName')
```

I would like to remove "lastName" and add "soupCan" at runtime. Is this possible?

**Edit**

Further information: "soupCan" is generated at run time, I can't create a property to depend on it b/c I don't know what that string is going to be ahead of time. I don't have the space or time to explain this design pattern, but it is an edge case that we seem to need.

**Second Edit**

Looks like this has been addressed before on github https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1128

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my workaround to the issue, but I will happily accept anyone who comes up with a more elegant solution. *pardon my coffeescript*

```
###
   Add the property with the dynamic dependency key as a mixin after creating
   the dependency key in the context of the object
###
init: ->
    @_super()
    mix = Ember.Mixin.create({
        _fullName: (->
             @get('key_from_runtime') #some logic on this key goes here
        ).property(key_from_runtime)
    })
    mix.apply(@)
    @set('full_name_applied', true)

### Keep track of if the mixin has been applied ###
full_name_applied: false

### Depend on the shadow property that has the dynamic dependency key ###
fullName: (->
    if _.isNull(@get('_fullName'))
        '' #predefined blank value
    else
        @get('_fullName')
).property('_fullName', 'full_name_applied')
```

Answer (score 3):

This information is stored on an internal variable `_dependentKeys`. You probably want something like [`removeDependentKeys`](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/903f0e0d8f3a7bf07b6c35bb0a489ff382c43244/packages/ember-metal/lib/computed.js#L78). But, this is defined inside an immediate function so you won't be able to call it.

You can replicate the logic if you want, but probably a good idea to think of alternatives.

For instance, you could define a different computed property, `fullNameSoup` that depends on `firstName` and `soupCan` instead, and in calling code switch between those properties instead. Or wrap this switching logic into yet another computed property!

Comment: +1 for research and links to source. I'm not ready to accept yet, b/c I don't have a solution. Thanks though!

Comment: No worries. I would love to find someone who will answer this too! Because then they can answer a [question](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/how-does-the-ember-meta-object-system-work/1792) of mine as well. :)